# mysql fulltext search relevancy score not right

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a fulltext index on the name column. When I do a search for `ficus nit 15g*` in boolean mode I would expect `Ficus Nitida - Indian Laurel Fig` to be the top result. But all 3 items have same relevance score.

Is there any way to have more relevant result at the top?

Below is query with results.

```
mysql> SELECT phppos_items.name, MATCH (phppos_items.name) AGAINST ('ficus nit 15g*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as rel FROM `phppos_items` WHERE MATCH (phppos_items.name) AGAINST ('ficus nit 15g*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  ORDER BY `rel` DESC;
+-----------------------------------------+--------------------+
| name                                    | rel                |
+-----------------------------------------+--------------------+
| Ficus Benjamna - Weeping Banyon - 15gal | 0.0984337329864502 |
| Ficus Rubignosa - Rusty Leaf Fig 15gal  | 0.0984337329864502 |
| Ficus Nitida - Indian Laurel Fig 15gal  | 0.0984337329864502 |
+-----------------------------------------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT: tried answer

```
mysql> SELECT phppos_items.name, MATCH (phppos_items.name) AGAINST ('ficus* nit* 15g*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as rel FROM `phppos_items` WHERE MATCH (phppos_items.name) AGAINST ('ficus* nit* 15g*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  ORDER BY `rel` DESC;
+-----------------------------------------+--------------------+
| name                                    | rel                |
+-----------------------------------------+--------------------+
| Ficus Benjamna - Weeping Banyon - 15gal | 0.1812381148338318 |
| Ficus Rubignosa - Rusty Leaf Fig 15gal  | 0.1812381148338318 |
| Ficus Nitida - Indian Laurel Fig 15gal  | 0.1812381148338318 |
+-----------------------------------------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using a wildcard, the fulltext search only matches (and scores) on identical words. `Nitida` and `nit` are different words, and neither contribute to the score nor would they actually be found, e.g. `match(...) against ('nit')` would not return any of your sample rows.

Depending on your exact requirements, it might already be enough to append a wildcard to each search term, which will both find and score partial words, e.g. use

```
match(...) against ('ficus* nit* 15g*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This will not make exact matches more valuable than partial matches though, so you could also customize your score, e.g. match against both `nit` and `nit*` but weight the exact match higher, using something like

```
match(...) against ('>ficus >nit >15g ficus* nit* 15g*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as rel
```

using the [> <-operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html):

> These two operators are used to change a word's contribution to the relevance value that is assigned to a row. The > operator increases the contribution and the < operator decreases it.

This way, an exact match to `nit` will contribute more, while an inexact match to `Nitida` will still add some points. A thing to note is that the relevance is based on the rarity of the word, so a rare but wildcarded word might still be more relevant than the common but exact match.

You gain more control with a custom weight using something like

```
match(...) against ('ficus nit 15g' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 10 
+ match(...) against ('ficus* nit* 15g*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as rel
```

You can do the scoring independently from the search, but you can/have to decide if you want to find `Nitida` if you enter `Nit`, or if you just want to give it a better score (but only find it if has an exact match with a different search term). E.g. you would use either `WHERE MATCH(...) AGAINST ('ficus nit 15g*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` or `WHERE MATCH(...) AGAINST ('ficus* nit* 15g*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`.

Comment: wildcard everywhere didn't fix it. I put my query in question.

Comment: The behaviour I described is how it should work, and fits your original problem. See this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0c3b1018a8a66267bf4d649b2cc5c650). Now the hard part starts to figure out what is different for you. Could you check if you use a binary or cs collation for `name`, making it case sensitive (e.g. add your table description)? Can you recheck you copy&pasted everything 1:1 (no lowercase/uppercase difference,...)? Can you try to run my fiddle code on your server (with adjusted tablename)? Can you recreate your behaviour on fiddle?

Comment: The original poster abandoned his post regardless of that Solarflare gave a very solid solution to his problem.